# Regex to replace function with an other

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex statement to go through my code and replace a function with an alternative that takes different parameters.

The function I want to replace has this signature:

[Label( "some text", Tooltips.**ToolTipName**, typeof( someClass ) )]

I would like this to be replaced with.

[Tooltip( Tooltips.**ToolTipName** )]

Can someone assist in writing a regex statement that will detect the signature and extract the ToolTip variable so I can do this?

Thanks

Karl

Comment: Have you tried a Find/Replace: `Label( "some text", Tooltips.ToolTipName, typeof( someClass ) )` by `Tooltip( Tooltips.ToolTipNam )`?

Comment: Find and replace wont work. I need to extract the Tooltips.<ToolTipName> value and replace the whole line with ToolTip( Tooltips.ToolTipName )]. I know this is quite simple for regex but I am very rusty.

Comment: Have fun. I doubt regex should do this in any case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
.*Tooltips\.\w+.*
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/dL9uC2/1)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks I had to make a slight change but it now works :) I used .*Tooltips\.(\w+).* and ToolTip( Tooltips.$1 ).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the regex you'd use to find:

```
"\\[Label\\([^\\]]*(Tooltips\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)[^\\]]*\\)\\]"
```

which says "literal bracket and paren followed by label and literal open paren, then possibly anything except the closing bracket, then tooltip, then anything but closing bracket, then close bracket.

Once you've found it, use group(0) to match the entire label, and group(1) to match the "Tooltips.name".

Then replace group(0) with "[Tooltip(" + group(1) + ")]".

You may be able to simplify or be more exact if you are certain of whitespace and that all attributes are single-line or not.